# Maven LifeCycleExecutor with an incomplete configuration error

Tags: maven-2, hudson

I am using the latest version 1.341 of the Hudson CI to build my maven-2 project (built using 2.2.0). But I get some warnings which I don't see if executed via a command prompt. Can someone let me know, how to debug this issue?

```
----------------------------------------------------------

Executing Maven:  -B -f d:\work\software\data\hudson\jobs\bio\workspace\trunk\pom.xml install

[WARNING] 

************ WARNING ************

This Maven runtime contains a LifecycleExecutor component with an incomplete configuration.


LifecycleExecutor class: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor

Missing component requirement: org.apache.maven.project.MavenProjectBuilder



NOTE: This seems to be a third-party Maven derivative you are using. If so, please

notify the developers for this derivative project of the problem. The Apache Maven team is not

responsible for maintaining the integrity of third-party component overrides.





[WARNING] 

************ WARNING ************



This Maven runtime contains a LifecycleExecutor component with an incomplete configuration.



LifecycleExecutor class: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor

Missing component requirement: org.apache.maven.project.interpolation.ModelInterpolator



NOTE: This seems to be a third-party Maven derivative you are using. If so, please

notify the developers for this derivative project of the problem. The Apache Maven team is not

responsible for maintaining the integrity of third-party component overrides.





[WARNING] 

************ WARNING ************



This Maven runtime contains a LifecycleExecutor component with an incomplete configuration.



LifecycleExecutor class: org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutorInterceptor

Missing component requirement: org.apache.maven.ConfigurationInterpolator



NOTE: This seems to be a third-party Maven derivative you are using. If so, please

notify the developers for this derivative project of the problem. The Apache Maven team is not

responsible for maintaining the integrity of third-party component overrides.


[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] Reactor build order: 

[INFO]   parent

[INFO]   config
```

Comment: This is more of a bug report than a support issue.   I suggest taking it directly to the Hudson users list: http://n4.nabble.com/Hudson-users-f361316.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks very similar to [JENKINS-2373](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2373) (see [this comment](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-2373?focusedCommentId=126741&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_126741) in particular). Please try with maven 2.2.1.

Comment: Migration to Maven 2.2.1 fixed the problem.